# getting src element using domDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I am using domDocument. I am close but need help for the last little bit

I have this html just a snippet below.
There are a number of rows. I am trying to get the href.

so far i am doing the following:
I can get the table, tr, and td ok , but not sure what to do from there.

Thanks for any help

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('table') as $tableitem) {
    if ( $tableitem->getAttribute('class') == 'tableStyle02'){
        $rows = $tableitem->getElementsByTagName('tr');
        foreach ($rows as $row){ 
            $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

            $hrefs = $cols->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a'); 
        }     
    }
}
```

html snippet:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" class="tableStyle02"> 
    <tr> 
        <td><span class="Name"><a href="bin.php?cid=703&size=0">
               <strong>Conference Facility</strong></a></span></td>
        <td align="center" nowrap>0.00</td>
        <td align="center">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center">&nbsp;0 - 0 &nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center">&nbsp;Wired Internet,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me introduce you the concept of xpath, a query language for DomDocuments:

```
//table[@class="tableStyle02"]//a/@href
```

Reads as: Take the table tag with class attribute tableStyle02 and then the href attribute from within the a child tag.

Or as you had the foreach for `tr` and `td` elements as well:

```
//table[@class="tableStyle02"]/tr/td/a/@href
```

Now in that path, the a tag is a direct children of the td tag which is a direct children of the tr tag which is a direct children of the table tag. As you can see, with xpath it is much easier to formulate the path to the element than writing everything in PHP code.

Apropos PHP code, in PHP this *can* look like:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$href = $xp->evaluate('string(//table[@class="tableStyle02"]//a/@href)');
```

The variable `$href` then contains the string: `bin.php?cid=703&size=0`.

---

This example is with a string (`string(...)`), so `->evaluate` returns a string, which is created from the first found attribute node. Instead you can return a nodelist as well:

```
$hrefs = $xp->query('//table[@class="tableStyle02"]/tr/td/span/a/@href');
#             ^^^^^                                       ^^^^
```

Now `$hrefs` contains the usual `DOMNodeList`, here it contains all the href attribute nodes:

```
echo $hrefs->item(0)->nodeValue; # bin.php?cid=703&size=0
```

Take care that if you use only one slash `/` to separate tags, that they need to be direct children. With two slashes `//` it can be a descendant (child or child of child (of child (of ...))).

Comment: this is great and all new. So i have played a little and i have one more question. My table has many rows with multiple hrefs. I did  $href = $xp->evaluate('string(//table[@class="tableStyle02"]/tr/td/a/@href)'); but only got the first. How do i get all?

Comment: Sure, I edited the answer for that variation. You could also then `foreach` over `$hrefs` as you did before. So both methods work well together.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [getAttribute()](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) on the individual DOMElement instances, (just as you used it the second line of the example):

```
foreach ($hrefs as $a_node) {
    if ($a_node->hasAttribute('href')) {
        print $a_node->getAttribute('href');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to navigate your way down the DOM hierarchy to use `getElementsByTagName`:

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('table') as $tableitem) {
    if ($tableitem->getAttribute('class') == 'tableStyle02'){
        $links = $tableitem->getElementsByTagName("a");
    }
}
```

`$links` at this point is now a [`DOMNodeList`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), so you can iterate through it:

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('table') as $tableitem) {
    if ($tableitem->getAttribute('class') == 'tableStyle02'){
        $links = $tableitem->getElementsByTagName("a");
        $hrefs = array();
        foreach ($links as $link) {
            $hrefs[] = $link->getAttribute("href");
        }
    }
}
// Do things with $hrefs
```