# Getting the first node in XPath nodelist results

Tags: php, domdocument

So let's say I want to grab the first h2 element.  I was under the impression from googling that something like

```
$xpath->query('(//h2)[1]');
```

should work, but that still returns a DOMNodeList instead of a node.  So what's going wrong here?

Comment: even if the xpath could only ever return a single result, you will ALWAYS get a nodelist. Just grab `$nodelist->item(0)` and move on. http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Comment: I see, thanks! That'll work. Wasn't aware the result would always be a nodelist instead of a node.

Comment: it makes it easier. otherwise you'd have to explictly test the query results to see if it's a node or nodelist everytime. So might as well just return a nodelist regardless of how many (or few) results there were.

Comment: If you were looking, for example, just to get the element's text content then [`evaluate()`](http://php.net/domxpath.evaluate) might be helpful too: `$text = $xpath->evaluate('string(//h2)');`

Comment: A good related/pair question probably is: [getting src element using domDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11593704/367456)

Answer (score 2):

> but that [`$xpath->query('(//h2)[1]');`] still returns a DOMNodeList instead of a node. So what's going wrong here?

The [`DOMXpath::query()`](http://php.net/domxpath.query) method *always* returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/DOMNodeList) if the xpath expression use is syntactically correct. It will *never* return a single `DOMNode` element.

So this is *not* a *still* but just an *is*. So you need to access the first element of that nodelist via the `item()` method (it's zero-indexed in difference to the one-index in the xpath predicate):

```
$h2 = $xpath->query('(//h2)[1]')->item(0);
```

Take care here, that the `query` method will return `FALSE` if the xpath expression is invalid which then results in a fatal error here. So sometimes you need to verify the return value first (e.g. if you dynamically create the xpath expression).

If you in the end only want to get the text-content (string-value) of that h2 element, you can alternatively use the [`DOMXpath::evaluate()`](http://php.net/domxpath.evaluate) method. Per the xpath `string()` function will get the text value of the first node in the set *or* just an empty string:

```
$h2Text = $xpath->evaluate('string(//h2)');
```

I hope this is helpful.